# how would i get embed messages from a specific channel? [Discord.js V12]

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to get a number from an embed field value from all the embeds in a specific channel and combine those numbers into one big number

Currently fetching messages from a specific channel like this

```
async function fetchMessagesUntil(channel, endDate, lastID) {
        let messages = [];
        try {
            messages = (await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100, before: lastID })).array();
            for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                if (messages[i].createdAt.getTime() < endDate.getTime()) {
                    return messages.slice(0, i);
                }
            }
            return messages.concat(await fetchMessagesUntil(channel, endDate, messages[messages.length - 1].id));
        } catch {
            return messages;
        }
    }

    let end = new Date();
    end.setDate(end.getDate() - 2); // Subtract two days from now
    (await fetchMessagesUntil(channel, end)).forEach(x => console.log(x.content));
    message.delete()
```

but embeds are empty when logging it to console

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) at the docs. The `Message` class has many properties. [Message.content](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) can be empty, but the message object may contain other properties like [Message.embeds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds), [Message.attachments](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments), etc.

So in your code you would access the embeds like this:

```js
let result = 0;
(await fetchMessagesUntil(channel, end)).forEach((message) => {
    message.embeds.forEach((embed) => {
        console.log(embed);
        // result += ...
    });
});
```

Also take a look at [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) at the docs. There you can see all the methods and properties it has, access them and get what you want from the embeds.

When getting a value from embed's field, I would check if it is the field you want to extract a value from, for example by checking its [name](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedField). If you know that it is the wanted field, you can get the [value](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedField) from there. First use `!isNaN(fieldValue)`, so you know that the field value [is a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Then I would use `parseInt(fieldValue)` to [parse the string into an integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). And finally using the `+=` operator, [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) the field's numeric value to the final `result` variable.

Comment: but how would I add the results together when it's inside of a forEach?

Comment: You can map the result to the message embeds. `(await fetch...).map((message) => message.embeds)`. Now each element will be an array of the messages embeds. In 99% of the cases you'll only need the first one, so you can also use `.map((message) => message.embeds[0])`. Each element will be an embed or `undefined`.

Comment: @Lioness100 but doesn't that just do the same as his code with forEach?

Comment: Yes, but it will provide a variable in a higher scope, and will be able to use other variables there.

Comment: @Lioness100 okay but what's the variable? I don't think I set one and how would I use it to multiply the result into one (like 5 + 5 = 10) ?

Comment: @MathiasAC Just define an integer variable as I did in my answer. And as you go through the messages and embeds get the numeric value from the embed's field. Parse it and add using the `+=` operator to the result variable.

Comment: @SkulaurunMrusal I tried that
if I did 5 + 5 it would do 55 instead of 10

Comment: nevermind, I wasn't parsing correctly

code works as intended